# How to load a lot of images (9000)

Tags: rendering, image, loop, project, dynamic

Newbie here. I want to create a video of moving a camera down a hallway that has (pngs) as the portraits on the walls, kind of like a gallery. I have about 9000 images that I want to display as the portraits so trying to set this up manually would take forever. What is the best way to tackle this? Is there a way to generate this long hallway at design time with a script or something? Or is there a way to do this dynamically at runtime? Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you system will be able to handle 9000 PNG images loaded into memory to begin with?

Comment: That is a good question. I have 32 GB memory so I hope so. If not, I may need to do it more dynamically at runtime so that I don't have everything loaded at once. Maybe there's a way to do it in batches. Not sure if Blender supports any type of batch rendering.

Comment: What render engine will you be using? If EEVEE or using Cycles GPU acceleration it must fit into your video memory rather than system RAM

Comment: I’m not sure on render engine yet. Thanks for the info about video memory.